# Adding View to existing table row

Tags: android

I m trying to add an image into the existing table row in the xml layout. But something is wrong, having NullPointerException. Can u pls tell me the way to add any view to the existing row in the xml. thnx

```
    TableLayout tbl= (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    TableRow row= (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tblHips);
    ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //image.setImageResource()
    row.addView(image);
    tbl.addView(row);
```

This my layout-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Waist"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText02"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblHips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To make it simple I have deleted some other rows with the same type of views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tblHips);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        row.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: What is this -"imageView" in  findViewById(R.id.imageView); Theres no imageView in my layout. The table row is blank. I want to put views dynamically into it. I thought I wud make an imageview from an exsting image and then insert into row

Comment: Its not working. 1 more thing, in my xml table layout there r already some rows with views. Now if I use this code it says-..."The specified child already has parent, u must call removeView() on the child's parent....

Comment: pls see the edited code, though I will add a textView and a edittext into the row in the end. But I m trying with an imageView now

Comment: try my update code remove the parent view don't add the row view into the tablelayout bcoz it is already add in xml file so try this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18395/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-tanvir)

Comment: so did in mine when I restarted the emulator...thanx now I m trying to add textview and edittext..see how it goes\

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it should work

```
TableLayout tbl= (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
TableRow row= new  TableRow(getApplicationContext());

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, row);

ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
row.addView(image);

tbl.addView(row);
```

Comment: Its not working. ! more thing, in my xml table layout there r already some rows with views. Now if I use this code it says-..."The specified child already has parent, u must call remove View() on the child's parent....